# Why is it bad practice to have an auto-increment primary key as a URL identifier?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've read that it's bad practice to have the following url `https://www.example.com/posts/{post_id}` where `post_id` corresponds to the post's primary key (see below).

I don't care that users know how many posts there are and my I'm handling authorization on the backend so that a user can only access their posts (so even if a bad actor knows someone's post_id, they won't have access to it). I'm using Postgres and also don't envision moving databases.

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (
  PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
  post_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);
```

Comment: Where have you read this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have taken care of the obvious difficulties, but I would still advise something less interpretable.

After all, if someone knows that "n" is valid in the URL, then they can try to get in using any value from 0 - n.  Giving such hints seems like an unnecessary hint to those who have less than honorable intentions.

Comment: That holds for any information you provide in the URL. It maps to something the backend will use to access a post.